# Http post with angular 2, cant set session on post

Tags: angular

Got this in angular 2:

```
let body = JSON.stringify(this.jiraConfig);
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.post('http://localhost:3007/api_jira/login', body, options).subscribe(...
```

I need to save a session on my backend. It works when I run it from postman. But when I post from angular, the backend do not set the session.

Why do I need to set options at all in my post? My IDE says it's optional? Anyway, I probably need to insert some setting in the header to allow a session being stored. Any ideas?

**Update**
This is my postman request genereated to curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: c730242e-0497-7344-35b1-f0addca9e7b6" -d '{"host":"xxx","basic_auth":{"username":"xxx","password":"xx"}}' "http://localhost:3007/api_jira/login"
```

This is the info from chrome dev tools, network, header-tab:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3007/api_jira/login
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:3007
Response Headers
view parsed
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override
Content-Type: application/json
set-cookie: connect.sid=s%3AM04ERSgj6F-5wKHwX1XY3G8CO6ZqfEHX.Xflr7ueknyg%2FYHvHIDqBp4ogfddfVdRwJS7GV4bniMk; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 19 May 2016 08:17:58 GMT
Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 08:16:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Request Headers
view parsed
POST /api_jira/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3007
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 89
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ca;q=0.2,nb;q=0.2
Request Payload
view parsed
{"host":"xx.atlassian.net","basic_auth":{"username":"xx","password":"xx"}}
```

Chrome post converted to curl:

```
curl 'http://localhost:3007/api_jira/login' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:4200' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,ca;q=0.2,nb;q=0.2' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:4200/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data-binary '{"host":"xx.atlassian.net","basic_auth":{"username":"xx","password":"xx"}}' --compressed
```

This is my backend (node) where I'm trying to some data (jiraConfig) in my session:

```
server.post('/api_jira/login', function(req, res){
    var jiraConfig = req.body;
    checkIfJiraConfigIsValid(jiraConfig, function(error, resp){
      if(error){
        res.status(401).send('Not authorized')
      }else{
        req.session.jiraConfig = jiraConfig;
        res.status(200).send();
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: Could you add in your question what you did in Postman? Thanks!

Comment: @ThierryTemplier,  I have updated the question.

Comment: Thanks! What do you exactly mean by session? The backend uses the payload to initialize the session? Could you also provide the request details for Angular2 from dev tools (network tab)?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier, Updated the question with server code and info from chrome dev tools.

Comment: With Angular2 do you receive the payload on the server? I mean: what is the content of `jiraConfig`? I added an answer with a possible solution... but it's just a guess without this hint

Comment: Yes. The payload is received. I've imported the Headers from @angular/http.

Comment: Is this payload different from the one received using Postman?

Comment: No they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

A possible problem would be that you forgot to import the `Headers` class so the `Content-Type` header isn't set in your request and the server can't deserialize your payload.

```
import { Headers, ... } from '@angular/http';
```